# c++ new without storing object

Tags: c++, new-operator

I've taken over some legacy C++ code (written in C++03) which is for an application that runs on an RTOS. While browsing the codebase, I came across a construct like this:

```
...
new UserDebug(); ///<User debug commands.
...
```

Where the allocation done using `new` isn't stored anywhere so I looked a bit deeper and found this

```
class UserDebug
{
  public:
    ///Constructor
    UserDebug()
    {
        new AdvancedDebug();      
        new CameraCommand();     
        new CameraSOG();         
        new DebugCommandTest();  
        new DebugCommand();      
        // 30 more new objects like this
    };

    virtual ~UserDebug(){};
};
```

I dug deeper into each of the class definitions and implementations mentioned and couldn't find any reference to `delete` anywhere.

This code was written by the principal software engineer (who has left our company).

Can anyone shed some ideas on why you would want to do something like this and how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: I would look for side effects in the various constructors.

Comment: Using RAII they could enable some debugging features, And for memory leaks? i don't know if don't have the complete code. Try ASAN.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into the constructors of those classes you’ll see that they have interesting side effects, either registering themselves with some manager class or storing themselves in static/global pointer variables á la singletons.

I don’t like that they’ve chosen to do things that way - it violates the Principle of Least Surprise - but it isn’t really a problem. The memory for the objects is probably (but not necessarily) leaked, but they’re probably meant to exist for the lifetime of the executable so no big deal.

(It’s also possible that they have custom `operator new`s which do something even odder, like constructing into preallocated  static/global storage, though that’s only somewhat relevant to the ‘why’.)

Comment: I was thinking the same... could as well have been a static global instead of a new though

Comment: @PepijnKramer static globals may not be initialised in the required order

Answer (score 1):

If these objects created once they might be expected to have the lifetime of the application (similar to singletons) and thus should never be deleted.
Another way to capture pointer is through overloaded [operator new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new): both global and class specific. Check if there are any overloads that implement some sort of garbage collection.